# How to fix remove whitespace from email headers in classic ASP?

Tags: asp-classic, jmail

I have a email function which sends email. The thing is done in classic ASP/VBScript and uses

```
Set objMail = Server.CreateObject("JMail.SMTPMail")
```

JMail. 
How can I remove extra whitespace (= bad MIME encoding) in the header?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. The solution was simple when I figured out what to do.

```
 objMail.MimeVersion = "1.0"
        objMail.SimpleLayout = true
        objMail.ContentTransferEncoding = "base64"
        objMail.Charset = "UTF-8"
```